# Not able to install scikit-learn on Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: scikit-learn, pi

I was trying to install scikit learn on Raspberry Pi 3 B+, with code,
python3.8 -m pip install scikit-learn==0.23.2
initially the pi was working fine showing the progress, after above 1 hour, monitor went off and the green LED on Rpi is ON all the time (before it was like blinking).
Now the Rpi seems to be ON with red and green LED full time ON, and not able to see the progress, and not detecting the input given through keyboard and mouse. its about 5 hours.

it will be very helpful for me, if someone explains me why this happens.

Thanking you in advance.